# Sacar números divisibles entre 3 con un ciclo for. Por medio de una salida estándar input

Tags: python, bucle-for, bucles

Intente algo asi pero no logro obtener lo que quiero. Esto es mas por practica pero me gustaria encontrar una solucio.

```
x = int(input("Ingrese un valor entero: "))

for c in x:
if x % 3 == 0:
    continue
print(x)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Corrige la indentación. En python para delimitar los bloques de código y saber que estructuras están dentro de cada bloque la indentación es fundamental.
2. La primera variable del `for` es la que va a tomar los valores en cada ciclo, por lo que dentro de tu `for`, usa `c`, No `x`
3. Debes realizar el `for` en un rango de valores, no para un valor específico, por tanto, usa `range`.

Te adjunto tu código con las correcciones correspondientes:

```
x = int(input("Ingrese un valor entero: "))

for c in range(0,x):
    if c % 3 == 0:
        continue
    print(c)
```

Usando `List Comprehension` puedes reducir tu código a solo dos líneas:

```
x = int(input("Ingrese un valor entero: "))
[print(c) for c in range(0,x) if c % 3 == 0]
```

O bien, calcular todos los múltiplos de 3 hasta el valor introducido:

```
x = int(input("Ingrese un valor entero: "))
[print(c) for c in range(3,x,3)]
```

Comment: Entiendo no sabia eso de que delimitar los bloques de codigo pero ya con esto me queda mas que claro!!!. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Me alegra que te ayude. Considera aceptar la respuesta como correcta. Saludos.